# SearchView Suggestions

Tags: android, firebase, searchview, search-suggestion

I'm working with SearchView but I would like to add suggestions. Any help ?

Here's part of my code

```
  public void recherche(String texte){
    Query mQuery= 
dbref.orderByChild("spécialité").startAt(texte).endAt(texte+"\uf8ff");




FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class,ViewHolder>
firebaseRecyclerAdapter= 
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<entreprises_class, ViewHolder>
            (entreprises_class.class,R.layout.entreprises_list, 
               ViewHolder.class,mQuery) {
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am looking for a way to add suggestions to m searchview. I don't know how